# Can I open any Application with this code in windows phone?

Tags: windows-phone

I would like to programmatically open an app in windows phone.
i found the following code to open an excel file:

```
var wbt = new WebBrowserTask();
wbt.URL = "http://example.com/file.xlsx";
wbt.Show();
```

could I use this code to open an .exe file?

Comment: Obviously, an .exe file wouldn't run on Windows Phone, so what would you expect opening it to give you?

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not programmatically open an app. Instead, it opens a web browser, navigates it to the xlsx file URI. Then, Internet Explorer recognizes file type from either extension or MIME type, and launches Excel.

With exe file, you’re only gonna get a message saying something like “Unsupported file format”.